# How to "smooth" boundary of scatter in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, scatter

I have a matrix `A` of size `nx2` collecting 2D points in Matlab. It is uploaded [here](https://filebin.net/gzxr6gap76yxq2ij) (unfortunately, I cannot reproduce it with a simple code).

When I plot them using `scatter` I get the following picture, where

- The black region is non convex
- The boundary of the region is very "unsmooth", the dots of the scatter are quite visible along the boundary.

`scatter(A(:,1), A(:,2), 50,'k', 'filled')
xlim([-4 4])
ylim([-4 4])`

[image]

**Question:** I would like to know whether there is a way to smooth the boundary of the region. I thought about using `patch`, but given that the region is non-convex, I don't know how to get its vertices. I also tried to increase the size of the scatter dots but the result is even worse. Are there some solutions?

Comment: You can get the boundary of the region using [`boundary`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/boundary.html).

Comment: Thanks, how can I color inside the boundary with black? I tried `k = boundary(A(:,1),A(:,2))`, `fill(A(k,1),A(k,2),'r')` but gives me error

Comment: See my answer below, that should work for any point cloud. Do you need to do any additional smoothing, or do you just want to obtain the boundary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`boundary`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/boundary.html) to find the *indices* of the data point that form the boundary. Next, you will have to select the data points using these indices to get the `x` and `y` coordinates that enclose your data.

```
% generate some random data
data = randn(100,2) + [3 4];

% find boundary, returns indices of points in data that define boundary
inds = boundary(data(:,1), data(:,2));
data_bound = data(inds,:);

% plot! 
figure(1); clf;
hold on;
fill(data_bound(:,1), data_bound(:,2), 'r'); % fill boundary
scatter(data(:,1),data(:,2),100, 'bx'); % plot data points
plot(data_bound(:,1), data_bound(:,2), 'k', 'linewidth', 2); % boundary
```

[image]